# Rational points on $y^2 = 12x^3 - 3$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove by elementary arguments that the only rational point on the title curve is $(x, y) =(1,\pm 3)$.

My attempt was the standard approach of factoring $(y+i\sqrt 3)(y - i\sqrt 3) = 12x^3$, but it seems as one proceeds in the usual manner, this doesn't yield the required result ?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Consider a line L with slope $m$ that passes through the point $(1,3)$. Then L will be of the form $y=m(x-1)+3$. Now consider the intersection of this line with the curve given. To get rational points you need to have $m$ as rational.

Note: even though you get a cubic in $x$ but one of the roots is $x=1$ So using symmetric polynomials it will be easy to get other roots in terms of $m$.