# Describe the rational points on $y^2 = 11 - 2x^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Describe the rational points on the title curve.

My attempt: Consider the line $L$ with slope $m$ that passes through the point $(1, 3)$. To obtain rational solutions, we need to have $m$ rational. Then $L$ will be of the form $y = m(x-1) + 3$. Now consider the intersection of $L$ with the title curve.

Note that, although the resulting equation will be a cubic in $x$, we already know that $x=1$ is a root, so it may be somewhat easier to factor the equation and possibly derive further information. But this seems not to be getting us any further ?

Comment: Here is the [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603644/rational-points-on-y2-12x3-3)  for $y^2=12x^3-3$.

Comment: @Dietrich, unfortunately that related post has no answers yet, the only suggested hint is of the idea in my attempt, which as i said, seems not to be yielding the required result.

Comment: It would be an improvement to include the elliptic curve's equation in the body of your Question, not really for the title only to convey this critical piece of the problem

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that $(-\frac52,\frac{13}2)$ is a rational solution.

**Additionally:**

This is an elliptic curve, whose points (including a point “at infinity” in the $y$-direction) form a group, with the infinite point being the identity. The famous chord-and-tangent process allows addition on the curve. By knowing the point $(1,3)$, you can try doubling it: draw the tangent to the curve at this point, and by Bézout, there is one additional intersection with the tangent, beyond the double contact at $(1,3)$. The symmetric point to this third intersection will be twice the original point. Since the derivative is $-1$ there, the line $Y=-X+4$ must have a third intersection. Of course, it’d have been possible for the third intersection to be at $(1,3)$ again: this would happen if the point was an inflection point. It didn’t happen, though, and $(\frac52,-\frac{13}2)$ is the other intersection. So $(-\frac52,-\frac{13}2)=[2](1,3)$, the doubled point. To find more points, draw the line from $(1,3)$ to $(-\frac52,-\frac{13}2)$ and look for the third intersection.

An expert will tell you that the real question is what the structure of the group of *all* rational points on the curve may be. Although I haven’t checked that $(1,3)$ is not a torsion point, this does look likely, in which case the rank of the group will be $\ge1$. Good luck in trying to find points that are not in the group spanned by $(1,3)$.

Comment: Thanks @Lubin, may you kindly reconsider the question in its present form.

Comment: That's much better !, though an elementary argument would have been more desirable.

Comment: Well, your original idea was fine. The step you didn’t take, though, was to use the slope $m=-1$. Then you would have had a double intersection of the line with the curve, forcing another rational point. I’m assuming you know about Bézout. With that alone, you could have found as many points as you like (assuming always that your original point is not torsion).